# Keep Process Running after Quitting NetCat

Tags: windows-7, linux, netcat

I am using NetCat on Windows 7 Professional to connect to my linux machine at home. I need to run a process and make it keep running after I close NetCat (Cmd Console).

However when I close and then connect and check the Process List my Process isn't running.
Is there any way I can keep it running after I close NetCat?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the process running when the terminal which has started it closes, you should detach it from the shell and ignore signals.
You can do that by using the `&` character at the end of your command-line, it runs the process in background, and by using `nohup` at the beginning, which catch disconnect signals and hide them to the process.
Alternatively, you can use `detach`, which lets you regain control over the process when you reconnect. `screen` can also be used for this purpose.

Comment: nohup doesn't work. I tried detach as well but same thing happened. Screen gives me an error that I am not in a Terminal Session.